# How to remove impossible to remove white spaces in powershell

Tags: powershell, whitespace, license-key

Working on a PowerShell script to basically check current available 365 Licenses and pick one to assign to a new user (I know some of it's kinda jank but it's in progress).

It outputs the data collected by `Get-MsolAccountSku` to an **array** and then selects which license by **index** and joins it to the tenant ID from:

```
(Get-MsolDomain | Where-Object {$_.isInitial}).name
```

But no matter what I do to remove the whitespace i.e.: using `trim`, using `replace`, using `regex replaces` it always keeps a space around the Name of the License so it shows like:

```
Redactedtenantname: FLOW_FREE
```

Instead of:

```
Redactedtenantname:FLOW_FREE
```

I did also look at trying to either use `-f` somehow to format it but I couldn't figure out how to get it to play nice.

The other idea that I think could potentially work is to export it to CSV temporarily and import from CSV to see if getting the credential from CSV would clear any weird whitespace / format.

Just wondering if anyone's run into anything similar/might know what to do.

I've altered some of the stuff here to get it to fit so if the formatting of the output is a bit weird (short of the whitespace) it might just be how I copied it across.

Also if it helps the final `$sku` variable I get is a `System.String`

```
#Get Tenancy name (For license assignment)
$Tenant = (Get-MsolDomain | Where-Object {$_.isInitial}).name

#Get list of licenses
$test = Get-MsolAccountSku | select -ExpandProperty AccountSkuID

#Read host for selection of license (at this time only does 1 at a time will improve on) 
$selection = Read-Host "Pick an object on the list i.e 1 for the first item 2 for the second etc"

#the array starts at 0 so just subtracting from the selection to make it 1-1 i.e 1 equals one 2 equals 2 etc.
$select = $selection - 1

#this selects an object from the array based on the number selected and altered above
$license = $test | Select-Object -index $select

#Manipulating the data selected above to make it fit our needs below Splitting at the : and replacing uneccessary data 
$365license = @($license -split ':')
$3651 = $365license -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',''
$3652 = $361 -replace "redactedtenantsname",""
$tenant1 = $tenant -replace ".onmicrosft.com",""


#Joining tenancy name to formatted license name
$presku1 = "$tenant1",":","$3652"
-join $presku1

$sku           = "$presku1"
$upn = "redactedtestuserupn"

Set-msoluserlicense -userprincipalname "$upn" -addlicenses "$sku"
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary string manipulation in your code, and it's not clear where, specifically, the extra space shows up, and whether it may be an output-formatting artifact. Please consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: I might try reduce it down tonight but if it helps it's somewhere in the following if I had to guess I think it's either when the property is initially grabbed or when it's selected from the array (Apologies for the compressed format I'm not a regular poster). Nearest I can tell it shouldn't be how it's displaying that is the issue. 
`$test = Get-MsolAccountSku | select -ExpandProperty AccountSkuID
$selection = Read-Host "Pick an object on the list i.e 1 for the first item 2 for the second etc"
 one 2 equals 2 etc.
$select = $selection - 1
$license = $test | Select-Object -index $select`

Comment: [`Get-MsolAccountSku`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolaccountsku?view=azureadps-1.0#outputs) outputs `[Microsoft.Online.Administration.AccountSKU]` instances, so I'd start with how their `.AccountSkuID` property values _stringify_ (unless they already _are_ strings). In general, please don't respond in _comments_ (unless to notify others of having made an update to the question), please update your question direclty.

Comment: Test line by line and variable by variable and see where your code failing, once you get that line give us an example input and your expected output.

Comment: Consider enabling strict mode (```Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"```) - it'll help with debugging. For example, ```$3652 = $361 -replace "redactedtenantsname",""``` references variable ```$361``` which doesn't exist, and ```$presku1 = "$tenant1",":","$3652" -join $presku1``` is trying to join with the uninitialised variable ```$presku1```. Also consider renaming your variables to meaningful names - e.g. ```$test``` should maybe be ```$accountSkuIds```. It'll be clearer in later code what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the core of your problem is that you've got a string in the format `<account>:<skuId>` and you want to replace the `<account>` part with something else.

```
# equivalent to
# $Tenant = (Get-MsolDomain | Where-Object {$_.isInitial}).name
$tenantDomain = "my_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
$tenantName   = $tenantDomain -replace ".onmicrosoft.com", "";
# e.g. "my_tenant_name"

# equivalent to
# $test = Get-MsolAccountSku | select -ExpandProperty AccountSkuID
$accountSkuIds = @(
    # the unique string ID of the account/SKU combination.
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolaccountsku?view=azureadps-1.0#outputs
    "my_other_tenant:ENTERPRISEPACK"
    "my_other_tenant:AAD_BASIC"
    "my_other_tenant:FLOW_FREE"
    "my_other_tenant:POWER_BI_STANDARD"
);

# ask the user which item they want to use
$selectedIndex = 3;

# get the selected sku from the array, remembering that arrays are
# zero-based we we need to subtract 1 from the user's selection
$accountSkuId = $accountSkuIds[$selectedIndex - 1];
# e.g. "my_other_tenant:FLOW_FREE"

# split the string "<account>:<sku>" into the array @( "<account>", "<sku>" )
# and then take the *second* item (i.e. [1])
$skuId = @( $accountSkuId -split ":" )[1];
# e.g. "FLOW_FREE"

# convert the @( "<new_account>", "<sku>" ) into the string "<new_account>:<sku>"
$license = @( $tenantName, $skuId ) -join ":";
# e.g. "my_tenant_name:FLOW_FREE"

# call the api
$upn = "my_upn";
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses $license;
```